# Why is GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag returning null?

Tags: unity

I'm currently working on refactoring my gravity simulator, but I'm running into a problem. I have two `GameObject`s, both tagged with the tag `"Body"`, as you can see below:

[image]

[image]

I'm attempting to cache a list of all `GameObject`s like so:

> ```
> private GameObject[] _bodies;
>
> ...
>
> public void Start()
> {
>     ...
>     this._bodies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Body");
>     ...
> }
> ```

When I try to use the value `this._bodies` though, as seen in the `foreach` loop below, I get a `NullReferenceException`.

> ```
> foreach(GameObject body in this._bodies)
> {
>     ...
> }
> ```

I have verified that the value of `this._bodies` is `null`, using this piece of code:

> ```
> Debug.Log(this._bodies);
> ```

I'm honestly stumped as to why `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` is returning `null` when I run it. Is there a way to solve this?

For reference, here's the full code involved:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class GravityComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public double gravitationalConstant = 6.674 * Mathf.Pow(10, -11);
    public Vector3 startingForce;

    private GameObject[] _bodies;
    private Dictionary<GameObject, double> _massProducts;
    private Rigidbody _bodyRigidbody;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initalize various private values and caches, like the
    /// cache of bodies, masses, etc.
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        this._bodyRigidbody.AddForce(this.startingForce);
        this._bodyRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        this._bodies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Body");
        this._massProducts = this._bodies.ToDictionary(
            body => body,
            body => 
                  this.gravitationalConstant 
                * this._bodyRigidbody.mass 
                * body.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass
        );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate the attractions between two separate bodies, and
    /// then apply the calculated attraction.
    /// </summary>
    public void ApplyAttraction()
    {
        foreach(GameObject body in this._bodies)
        {
            Vector3 bodyPositionDifference = body.transform.position - this.transform.position;
            double attraction = this._massProducts[body] / bodyPositionDifference.sqrMagnitude;
            this._bodyRigidbody.AddForce(bodyPositionDifference * (float)attraction);
        }
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(this._bodies);
        this.ApplyAttraction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*gulp*

Simple typographical errors, the bane of every programmer ever. In the end, all I had to do was swap these two lines, simply because I was attempting to use the `Rigidbody` of the object *before* I assigned it a value.

> ```
> this._bodyRigidbody.AddForce(this.startingForce);
> this._bodyRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
> ```

After swapping, these two lines became this:

```
this._bodyRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
this._bodyRigidbody.AddForce(this.startingForce);
```

Some days it just pays to double-check things.